# Unity Player Movement Script is not working correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a very broad question.

I am working on a 2d sidescroller platformer game and I just made the player movement script. However, when the player runs into a wall while in the air while moving left or right, the player just stays there and doesn't fall.

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nx53pwjgbY) shows what happened.

This is my code for the player movement script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    private float moveSpeed;
    private float dirX;
    public bool facingRight = true;
    private Vector3 localScale;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        localScale = transform.localScale;
        moveSpeed = 5f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && rb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 350f);
        }

        if (Math.Abs(dirX) > 0 && rb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y == 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            anim.SetBool("isFalling", false);
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y > 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", true);
        }

        if (rb.velocity.y < 0)
        {
            anim.SetBool("isJumping", false);
            anim.SetBool("isFalling", true);
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX, rb.velocity.y);
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (dirX > 0)
        {
            facingRight = true;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0)
        {
            facingRight = false;
        }

        if (((facingRight) && (localScale.x < 0)) || ((!facingRight) && (localScale.x > 0)))
        {
            localScale.x *= -1;
        }

        transform.localScale = localScale;
    }
}
```

I have tried adding:

```
if ((Math.Abs(dirX) == 5 && Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == 1 && rb.velocity.y == 0) || (Math.Abs(dirX) == -5 && Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") == -1 && rb.velocity.y == 0))
        {
            anim.SetBool("isFalling", true);
            dirX = 0;
        }
```

But it just makes it crazier.

Can anyone help me? (please no roast)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is most likely that your character is colliding with the walls and they are both physical objects. When two objects collide with one another, one response when two surfaces rub into each other is friction.

One solution is to add a slippery [Physics Material](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicMaterial.html) to your player by setting the friction down to 0.0f.

A modified version of this solution that I have used is to create a copy of your collider on your object, that has the slippery material while leaving your base material the same. Then make this new collider slightly wider but shorter. What will happen is for any horizontal collision the slippery material will be used, but for vertical your original material with friction will be used. Meaning when you walk on a slope or on the ground, your player will have friction, but when walking or jumping into a wall, you will have no friction.

Another solution I just learned about is [Platform Effectors](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlatformEffector2D.html). Using this component you can set the friction of an object to depend on what side you hit it from. I believe to get it working, you just need to check a box on your collider to be used by an effector, add the component, then check off the bool on the Platform Effector called `Use Side Friction`.

Let me know if you have issues implementing either solution. I can try to provide more details or possibly get some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your colliders associated with the GameObject. If you have just a rectangle, then that shouldn’t be it. If you are using custom made gravity, then the problem might be that you are or unity is resetting the gravity force when it hits a wall. You could change the tag or something. I am not an expert on unity2d, but I hope this helps.